# Группировка по двум полям в DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, обработка-данных

Имеется некий набор данных `tr_new`, в нем есть столбец `mcc_code`, `tr_day`, `amount`:

```
    mcc_code    amount  tr_day
0   4814    -2245.92    0
1   4814    -5614.79    6
2   4814    -1122.96    8
3   4814    -2245.92    11
4   4814    -2245.92    11
... ... ... ...
998285  6010    606397.26   178
998286  6010    11319.42    370
998287  6010    -44117.20   109
998295  5411    3897.56 440
998296  5411    20843.67    389
```

Делается группировка:

```
mccmax = tr_new.groupby(['mcc_code']).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 60000)
```

Я хочу дополнительно сгруппировать по `tr_day` чтобы вначале шел номер дня `tr_day` потом `mcc_code` и вычислить среднюю сумму операций за этот день по этому `mcc` коду.

Пишу:

```
mccmax = tr_new.groupby(['tr_day','mcc_code']).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 60000).mean()
```

Но получается совсем не то.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Не помог ваш вариант к сожалению.

Comment: А почему не помог? Так и вывел в консоли: _не помогаю_?  Прочтите ответ всё таки ещё раз внимательней.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
res = (tr_new
       .groupby(['tr_day','mcc_code'])
       .filter(lambda x: len(x) > 60000)
       .groupby(["tr_day", "mcc_code"])
       ["amount"]
       .mean()
```

---

PS в таких вопросах лучше всегда приводить небольшие примеры входных данных и результат, который вы хотите получить. Без этих данных ответы не могут быть протестированы и могут содержать ошибки.

Comment: А подскажите как лучше оформить фрагмент данных?
Проверил код,вывело: Series([], Name: amount, dtype: float64)

Comment: @AleksMir, [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)